# java array from newboston lesson

Tags: java, arrays

While going over newboston java tutorial, I am looking at array lessons and wondering why assigning variable in array is ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)]. I understand the 1+rand.nextInt(6) part but ++freq, I do not.

Because I come from other script background, I would think freq[roll] = 1+rand.nextInt(6) is the right way(but clearly not right).. can someone explain to me why ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)] works here?

Another words,

Aren't I doing

```
 freq[0] = 1+rand.nextInt(6);
 freq[1] = 1+rand.nextInt(6);
 freq[2] = 1+rand.nextInt(6);
  ------ continue till
 freq[9] = 1+rand.nextInt(6);
```

??

```
class apples {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int freq[] = new int[7];

    for ( int roll=1; roll < 10; roll++) {

        //++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];

        freq[roll] = 1+rand.nextInt(6);
    }
```

Comment: You are accessing elements outside array range(`freq[roll]`)

Comment: `++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)]` This will count how many times one number turns up. `freq[roll] = 1+rand.nextInt(6);` this will store what number came up on a roll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for the increment of value of `freq` array positioned at the `1+rand.nextInt(6)` index. What you're doing is assigning value `1+rand.nextInt(6)` to `freq[roll]`. So you are replacing the value at the position not incrementing it.

Comment: here `++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)]` you're accessing a random index and incrementing the value. here `freq[roll] = 1+rand.nextInt(6)` you're accessing `roll`th index of `freq` array and assigning a random value to it. These two things are not same. Hope it may help you!